# How can I insert contract with ShippingAddress?

Tags: salesforce, apex

I want to register a new Contract Object.
However, when I try to register it together with ShippingAddress, I get an error.

How do I add a ShippingAddress with a Contract Object?

■ Field is not writeable: Contract.ShippingAddres

```
Contract cont = (Contract) parser.readValueAsStrict(Contract.class);

Address a = new Address();
a.country = 'Japan';
a.city = 'Tokyo';

cont.ShippingAddress = a;

insert cont;
```

I ran New Contract in the GUI, and the second of the arrays has ShippingAddress registered.
I would like to do this with the Apex API as well.

■ The ShippingAddress of the second record is registered.

```
[
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "Contract",
      "url": "/services/data/v56.0/sobjects/Contract/8000T000000223IQAQ"
    },
    "Id": "8000T000000223IQAQ",
    "AccountId": "0010T00000Ox7sSQAR",
    "BillingAddress": null,
    "ShippingAddress": null,
    "OwnerId": "0055g00000GRB5vAAH",
    "Status": "Draft",
    "StatusCode": "Draft",
    "IsDeleted": false,
    "ContractNumber": "00000114",
    "CreatedDate": "2022-11-15T10:03:42.000+0000",
    "CreatedById": "0055g00000GRB5vAAH",
    "LastModifiedDate": "2022-11-15T10:03:42.000+0000",
    "LastModifiedById": "0055g00000GRB5vAAH",
    "SystemModstamp": "2022-11-15T10:03:42.000+0000",
    "LastViewedDate": "2022-11-15T10:03:42.000+0000",
    "LastReferencedDate": "2022-11-15T10:03:42.000+0000"
  },
  {

    "BillingStreet": "西新宿１丁目",
    "BillingCity": "新宿区",
    "BillingState": "東京都",
    "BillingPostalCode": "163-0590",
    "BillingCountry": "日本",
    "BillingAddress": {
      "city": "新宿区",
      "country": "日本",
      "geocodeAccuracy": null,
      "latitude": null,
      "longitude": null,
      "postalCode": "163-0590",
      "state": "東京都",
      "street": "西新宿１丁目"
    },
    "ShippingStreet": "西新宿１丁目",
    "ShippingCity": "新宿区",
    "ShippingState": "東京都",
    "ShippingPostalCode": "163-0590",
    "ShippingCountry": "日本",
    "ShippingAddress": {
      "city": "新宿区",
      "country": "日本",
      "geocodeAccuracy": null,
      "latitude": null,
      "longitude": null,
      "postalCode": "163-0590",
      "state": "東京都",
      "street": "西新宿１丁目"
    },
    .....
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/compound_fields_address.htm

> Standard address compound fields are read-only, and are only
> accessible using the SOAP and REST APIs. See [Compound Field
> Considerations and Limitations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/compound_fields_limitations.htm) for additional details of the
> restrictions this imposes.

Instead set single fields inside the address.

```
cont.ShippingCountry = 'Japan';
cont.ShippingCity = 'Tokyo';
insert cont;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. However, I can register through the GUI, but how do I register through the Apex API?

Comment: The ShippingAddress of the second record is registered. So, I want to register like second record.

Comment: You can read it but can't write it. That shouldn't be a big problem, the values are still OK in the ShippingStreet, ShippingCity etc, right? You can stop querying the ShippingAddress "field" and your problem should be gone? (there are more fields you can query but not write to). Alternative would be to process it out of the JSON somehow, painful but should be doable, let me know if you'd want to try it out.